# Group and sum multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Table with these columns:

```
id | name1 | score1 | name2 | score2
```

I need to transform the result of these two queries in one

```
SELECT name1, SUM(score1) as a
FROM partidos
GROUP BY name1
ORDER BY a DESC;

SELECT name2, SUM(score2) as b
FROM partidos
GROUP BY name2
ORDER BY b DESC;
```

The result is '`a + b`', I need this sum and the name in one query.

**Example:**

```
id |   name1  |  score1  |   name2  |  score2
1  | james    | 5        | carolina | 3
2  | carolina | 3        | troll    | 9
3  | mordor   | 6        | ent      | 5
4  | carolina | 1        | paul     | 3
5  | paul     | 18       | kek      | 1
```

**Result:**

```
paul 21
troll 9
carolina 7
mordor 6
ent 5
james 5
kek 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `UNION ALL` to combine the `Score1` and `Score2` in a single column then do the `SUM`

```
select Name, SUM(Total)
from
(
SELECT name1 as Name, score1 as Total
FROM partidos
union all
SELECT name2, score2 as Total
FROM partidos
) A
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: There's a bug in the union section, the selects should be `SELECT name1 as Name, score1 as Total FROM partidos UNION ALL SELECT name2 as Name, score2 as Total FROM partidos`